# Why the adverb "lately" is sometimes used with the present progressive?

Tags: present-perfect, adverbs, present-continuous

The following example is from this [video](https://youtu.be/K-uTam5RxyY). It is at 5 minutes and 48 seconds.

> You are killing it **lately**.

I am confused because as this [dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lately) says the adverb is usually used with perfect tenses, shouldn't have the teacher said the following?

> You have been killing it lately.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the teacher might as well have said: "have been". Both describe a new and/or temporary situation, which has been/is occurring lately.